# Android Fragment Force Close Error?

Tags: android

I am working on android fragment when i run my app in android 3.0 versions and above it's working fine but when i am trying to run below 3.0 it's giving forceclose error i am not understanding what is the wrong. Below is log cat errors and my code.

And if run my app in smart phone then i need to display view in another windown with out opening new activity. can you guide me how to do this. And it's working fine in tablet. I am sending working screen shot for tablet.

```
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.fragment_demo.MainActivity.getFragmentManager
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.example.fragment_demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-21 09:29:24.272: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    Button b1, b2, b3;   
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main_fdemo);     
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();   
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();  
        StartFragment sf = new StartFragment();   
        ft.add(R.id.myFragment, sf);     
        ft.commit();      
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);   
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); 

        b1.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);  
        b2.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);  
        b3.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick); 
    }   
    Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {        
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
            Fragment fragment = null;     
            if(v == b1){    
                fragment = new Fragment1();   
            }else if(v == b2){     
                fragment = new Fragment2();    
            }else if(v == b3){       
                fragment = new Fragment3();   
            }        
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);    
            ft.commit();  
        }   
    };

}

main_fdemo.xml:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


public class StartFragment extends Fragment
{     
    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_fragment, container, false); 
    }
}

start_fragment.xml:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select the Fragments"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{     
    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false); 
    }
}

fragment_1.xml code:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F97C7C"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select the Fragments"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Android Support Library to be backwards compatible down to API 4. While using the library you will use support methods like getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Now it's working. And if run my app in smart phone then i need to display view in another windown with out opening new activity & if i run in tablet it view should be in the same windown right side free space.I posted my whole code for this problem.

Comment: well theres a few ways you can do it without opening a new activity you could use fragment transactions to show/hide different fragments or use a DialogFragment or something..but you should get more familiar with fragments in the docs and if you have a more specific question after reading the docs you can post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer Android document. Android `Fragment` only supported in 3.0 and above. So below 3.0 fragment and fragment manager will not available. If you want to use fragment and fragment manager use Android compatible library and [refer to the Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android support Library for adding fragment support in below 3.0 device
check this link
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html